# Schedule push notification Parse unity

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, push, schedule

Can i use Parse.com Unity plugin to schedule push notification to the user once an action is done.

i.e) Notify the user in 1 hour that his building has been built.(as in coc an example)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Push Notifications is what you are looking for here, instead I think you want [Local Notifications](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iOS.LocalNotification.html). With Local Notifications, you schedule a notification to appear at a specified time (you usually schedule the notification when the player leaves the app, as you wouldn't normally want the notification to appear as they are playing it).

For example, you would do the following (not tested):

```
public void OnApplicationPause(bool isPaused)
{
        // If paused, then in background
        if (isPaused)
        {
            LocalNotification notification = new LocalNotification();
            notification.alertAction = "App Name";
            notification.alertBody = "The building is complete";
            notification.hasAction = true;
            notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // Set's the badge count
            notification.fireDate = dateBuildingWillBeFinished;

            NotificationServices.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
        }
        else // Entered the app
        {
            // Clear notifications
            NotificationServices.CancelAllLocalNotifications();
            NotificationServices.ClearLocalNotifications();
        }
}
```

Push Notifications are generally used to send messages to all players, or a group of players (such as players in the UK) to notify them of something, like a sale that is going on for in app purchases. Local Notifications are user specific, and can act more as reminders, such as your building has been completed or you haven't visited your town in a week etc.

Comment: If we use local notification it can't be sync to the server isn't?
If the building take 8 hours to build and if u uninstall and reinstall the app, it still works in COC.
Are they syncing the data to to the server? And how can they enable push even after reinstalling the app.

I guess  shephertz.com provide a solution for this.

Comment: No, local notifications can't be synced to the server. I'm not sure if CoC are, I don't understand why they would. When you reinstall the app, won't you have to allow the app to send you notifications again? In which case, they are probably just registering the local notification again when you close the newly installed app. I mean, it's possible to do it with Push Notifications, but it be a bit complicated and I don't see any advantage of it over local notifications for your use case.